# Guardar cambios cuando se minimiza la aplicación

Tags: android, android-studio

Es problema que tengo es el siguiente, tengo una aplicación desarrollada el cual tiene un login del login me lleva a la pantalla principal de la aplicación, en la pantalla principal de la aplicación se capturán los datos pero la captura de los datos se puede hacer en ese momento o bien llenar los datos y minimizar la aplicación para posteriormente continuar con el llenado de la información.

El problema surge cuando se minimiza la aplicación y al paso de un rato se da click al atajo de la aplicación el cual me lleva nuevamente al login y pues claro tengo que iniciar sesión nuevamente y llenar los datos.

Funciona correctamente solo si se usa el administrador de tareas ya que ahí me lleva directamente a la pantalla principal sin necesidad de llevarme al login.

En el AndroidManifest.xml ya tengo la configuración para que se guarden los datos si la aplicación se minimiza.

```
<activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Manager" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
    </activity>
```

Como hacer para que al dar click en el atajo de la aplicación me lleve a la pantalla principal solo si la aplicación se ha minimizado de lo contrario que se siga llevando al login

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿que tiene tu clase MainActivity para que cuando se minimizo esta no inicie aquí ?

Comment: Ninguna configuración especial solo sobrescribir los metodos del Activity onCreate,onStart,onResume,onDestroy....

Comment: has probado eliminando estos métodos?

Comment: no funciona onRestoreInstanceState()?

Comment: Eliminar, podria eliminarlos ya que no implemento nada especial en esos metodos que sobreescribo, @armen y si es como si no funcionara el onRestoreInstanceState(), pero solo cuando se intenta ejecutar desde el atajo de la aplicación.